# Understanding javascript function scopes by example

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between below 2 code snippets ?

i could not understand any differences between them. 
Both are using closures(as per my knowledge and correct me if i am wrong) 
and prints the same output that is 0,1,2,3,4.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    (function(){
        var tmp = i;
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log(tmp);
        }, 0)
    })();

}
```

and

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    setTimeout((function(tmp){
        return function() {
            console.log(tmp);
        }
    })(i), 0);

}
```

Comment: So I think they are rrally the same. Why are you so determined to find out the difference? If they work the same, then who cares?

Comment: No difference in outcome.  You just make a different type of closure at a slightly different level in each case.  There are often many different ways to achieve a given closure.

Comment: @Turtle : This code snippet was given to my friend during his interview and they had asked him to tell the differences.I was little bit surprised of this code so thought in case if i am missing something, will get it confirmed.

Comment: The first one is using IIFE, a JavaScript design pattern which produces a lexical scope using JavaScript's function scoping. If you remove the IIFE and directly access i variable instead of tmp, it will still give same result.

Comment: @brute_force: the second one also uses IIFE. "If you remove the IIFE and directly access i variable instead of tmp, it will still give same result" --- it will not for sure.

Comment: @zerkms Yes. So the first one is having IIFE warping the setTimeout function while the 2nd one is passing IIFE as first argument to setTimeout function.

Answer (score 0):

If you forget about the identifier resolution done by

```
var tmp = i;
```

and rewrite the first snippet to

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    (function(tmp){
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log(tmp);
        }, 0)
    })(i);

}
```

then the IIFE here creates a scope and sets delayed execution, while the IIFE in the second snippet creates a scope and returns a function with that scope.

Comment: And it's not the "difference" actually. Or is it? For me those are identical.

Comment: @zer Well, ... it's a difference like in what's the difference between images and maybe it could boil down to SoC in small. And it's always a challenge to think about execution contexts and their scopes. But, if I had encountered any of the snippets on their own, I don't think I would consider, not even remember the other. And there's a value in that too.

Comment: The question was asked on the interview. It implies the interviewer wanted to hear some *technical difference*, not "like in what's the difference between images"

Comment: Maybe he just wanted to hear some reasoning about JavaScript code. What kind of interview was it? @zer

Comment: @user152807 : This was an UI Dev interview and above code snippet was given to my friend in his Javascript round especially during the discussions over IIFE and Closures.